# Windows Batch make file not run if wrong key pressed?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a quick little installer and uninstaller app, because I seem to use these little resources a LOT, and it's set up to have y mean uninstall, and n mean end the script, standard stuff, the problem is if I type a non y or n key, it automatically uninstalls.

How can I make it fail on non y/n keys?

Also, can I make it display the entered key on a new line, so it's more visible?

Here's my script.

```
SET /P ANSWER=Do you want to uninstall? (Y/N)?
echo You chose: %ANSWER%
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :uninstall)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={n} (goto :end)
goto :end
```

~EDIT~
Changed the script to look like this, same behavior.

```
if /i %ANSWER% == y goto :uninstall else goto :end
```

Comment: Please move the 'I figured it out' part from the question to an answer, then mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Any reason you can't use something like `choice` with ErrorLevel instead? It's made specifically for this sort of usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET /P DELETE=Do you want to uninstall (Y/N)?
echo You chose: %DELETE%
if !DELETE! == y (goto uninstall) else (goto cancel)
```